# Why am I getting an InvalidProtocolBufferException when creating a Message.Builder from byte array but not an InputStream?

Tags: java, http, protocol-buffers

I'm working on a Servlet and trying to log the requests. The crucial part of the code causing the error is the following:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
    StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
    IOUtils.copy(request.getInputStream(), writer);
    Message.Builder builder = something of type com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessage.Builder;
    builder.mergeFrom(writer.toString().getBytes());
}
```

The final line of code above results in the following Exception:

```
com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException: Protocol message tag had invalid wire type.
```

However, when the code is switched to:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
    Message.Builder builder = something of type com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessage.Builder;
    builder.mergeFrom(request.getInputStream());
}
```

There is no error, and everything works fine. What could the problem be? I seem to need something similar to the first code snippet because I need to use the input stream a second time (once to write it to a file, and once to process the actual request).

Comment: How does your `data` get constructed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, I needed to use coded input and output streams so that the data could be read correctly. See my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4870528/how-should-i-record-httpservletrequests-that-are-sent-to-dopost-in-an-httpse/4963983#4963983) to my other question.

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
InputStream inputStream = request.getInputStream();

byte[] data = IOUtils.toByteArray(inputStream);
Message.Builder builder = something of type com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessage.Builder;
builder.mergeFrom(data);

// then use inputStream for something else
```

Comment: oops, forgot to copy that line of code from mine. Thanks, this doesn't effect the exception though.

Comment: Perhaps, you might want to take a look at `RepeatableInputStream` at http://www.jarfinder.com/index.php/java/info/org.zkoss.io.RepeatableInputStream . This way, you can wrap your `inputStream` with `RepeatableInputStream` so that you can use it multiple times.