# How do you save a HttpServletRequest so it can be resent?

Tags: jakarta-ee, servlets

I want to develop an authentication system where we if the authentication token has expired it will allow you to continue by storing your request prior to authentication being requested somewhere like a query parameter or a session object that is keyed to a query parameter.

For `GET` operations, it is easy enough to capture the query parameters as part of the query string and pass it back in later.  However, with `POST` which may not necessarily be `x-www-encoded` or `PUT`, `DELETE`, `OPTION` the operation is not as easy to deal with from what I can tell.

I was thinking of capturing the content using getServletInputStream() and putting it in a bytearray that gets stored with the request.  Then perform a playback on it using something like request dispatcher.  However, that may cause issues with the getParameter() method.

This is close but not necessarily what I wanted as it does not address the `getParameter()` method.

[How should I record `HttpServletRequest`s that are sent to `doPost` in an `HttpServlet` for later playback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4870528/how-should-i-record-httpservletrequests-that-are-sent-to-dopost-in-an-https)

Answer (score 0):

You could write your own `HttpServletRequest`, that takes everything from the originally request (parameters, headers, etc) and stores it in local variables. Then store your own request object in the session and use it later with request dispatcher.

You could run in a OutOfMemoryError, if your request is very large (fileuploads etc). So you might want to cache big parameters/parts/headers in a file.