# ByteArrayOutputStream .toByteArray(); Exception

Tags: android, protocol-buffers, httpurlconnection, bytearrayoutputstream

when i tryin to make thme method .toByteArray(); always fall in a exception, but the log doesn´t show, what can be the problem:

```
protected byte[] GetResponseBytes(HttpURLConnection conn)
{
    byte[] data2 = null;
    try
    {
        int nRead;
        byte[] data = new byte[16384];
        InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
        ByteArrayOutputStream buff = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        while ((nRead = is.read(data, 0, data.length)) != -1)
            buff.write(data, 0, nRead);

        buff.flush();
        buff.close();
        is.close();
        data2 = buff.toByteArray();
        return data2;

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Log.d(" ERROR ", "[ data loader - post response bytes ] "+ex.getMessage());
        return data2;
    }
}
```

and i call the method like this:

```
byte[] data = GetResponseBytes(conn);
            element = parser.parseFrom(data);
```

the parser is a protocolBuffer and make an excepcion

Answer (score 0):

You have closed the buffer "buff" at the line:
buff.close();
then you are accessing it.  Close it after accessing it - not before :-)

Comment: What is the exception you are getting?  Try putting a break point on the line where the Log call is rather than relying on the log itself.

Comment: com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException: Protocol message tag had invalid wire type.

Comment: OK, look at the accepted answer to a similar problem [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4870528/how-should-i-record-httpservletrequests-that-are-sent-to-dopost-in-an-https/4963983#4963983).  I think for your particular problem you need to read/write your byte array using a CodedOutputStream as described in the link.

Answer (score 0):

data2 = buff.toByteArray();
buff.flush();
buff.close();`